# Transformation to the normal

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

What reference papers should I look at for transformation to the multivariate normal of unimodal multivariate functions? For example, bivariate exponential dist to bivariate normal dist.

Comment: If you can't be bothered to write "distribution", why should one bother to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no single "multivariate exponential" - and in general, more than one way of getting multivariate anything, depending on which properties you want it to have. A few cases have a "natural" multivariate extension (in which case everyone will correctly guess the intent) but in general that's not so. In general, the *copulas* of two multivariate distributions will differ, which presents a number of potential issues (e.g. if you just transform the margins, then any of the usual multivariate exponentials will not be transformed to a multivariate normal).